# PhpStorm - close tabs that are opened while debugging

Tags: tabs, phpstorm

Is it possible in PhpStorm to close all tabs that were opened while debugging by one command?

Comment: Did you ever manage to find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a custom hotkey for one of the "close" editor tab actions, e.g. "Close others":
[image]

Not sure if that's what you're looking for though. What's the use case?

Comment: In the debug process, when i step through code, files that are not yet open will be opened automatically. These tabs I want to close after debugging at one click/hotkey. Otherwise there are too many open tabs in my view.